# Factory Girl associations creates new factory model instead of associate to existing one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations, factory-bot

error message:

```
 Failure/Error: let(:rubric_in_grenoble){ create(:rubric_in_grenoble) }

     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Name has already been taken
```

> So, as I suppose, the :rubric factory is tried to be created second
>   time (because the :rubric_in_grenoble should have association to the
>   same culture as :rubric_in_wroclaw). How should I change this code to
>   not create again same factory model, but to associate it with the
>   existing one?
>   I use Database Cleaner

I'm writing test to the model Population.

```
class Population < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :province
  belongs_to :culture

  validates_presence_of :province, :culture

  #some methods
end
```

It's associated to Province

```
class Province < ApplicationRecord
  enum terrain: [:sea, :plains, :hills, :mountains]
  validates :terrain, presence: true
  validates :name,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: true,
            format: {
                with: /\A[A-Za-z ]{3,30}\z/,
                message: "province name has to contain letters and spaces only"
  }
  has_many :populations

 ##some methods
end
```

And to Culture

```
class Culture < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :downcase_name
  validates :name, presence: true,
            format: {
                with: /\A[a-z]{3,20}\z/,
                message: "culture name has to contain letters only"
            },
            length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 20 }

  ##many-to-many associations to different model - tested correctly

  has_many :populations

end
```

In my test suite I use FactoryGirl and RSpec. Rails 5.0.1. I've got also simplecov installed (I'm 99.99% sure it's not interfering, but it's better to highlight this) and DatabaseCleaner works properly.

Culture and Province models are tested and everything's fine. In my FactoryGirl file for Populations there is:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :rubric_in_wroclaw, class: "Population" do
    association :province, factory: :wroclaw
    association :culture, factory: :rubric
    quantity 10
  end

  factory :javan_in_wroclaw, class: 'Population' do
    association :province, factory: :grenoble
    association :culture, factory: :javan
    quantity 15
  end

  factory :rubric_in_grenoble, class: 'Population' do
    association :province, factory: :grenoble
    association :culture, factory: :rubric
    quantity 25
  end
end
```

And in my population_spec.rb file I've got:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Population, type: :model do

  let(:rubric_in_wroclaw){ create(:rubric_in_wroclaw) }
  let(:javan_in_wroclaw){ create(:javan_in_wroclaw) }
  let(:rubric_in_grenoble){ create(:rubric_in_grenoble) }
  let(:pops){ [ rubric_in_wroclaw, javan_in_wroclaw, rubric_in_grenoble] }



  describe '#validations' #shoulda-matchers validations - GREEN

  describe '#methods' do
    describe '#global_population' do
      context 'without any pop' #without any fixture created
      context 'with many pops' do
        before { pops } <--- there is an error

        it 'is equal to 50' do
          expect(Population.global_population).to eq 50
        end

      end
    end**


  end

  describe '#factories' #each factory is tested separately - everything's ok


end
```

Repeated question (because post is very long)

> So, as I suppose, the :rubric factory is tried to be created second
>   time (because the :rubric_in_grenoble should have association to the
>   same culture as :rubric_in_wroclaw). How should I change this code to
>   not create again same factory model, but to associate it with the
>   existing one?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

Probably you are giving duplicate value to your `Province.name` field. The [sequence](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Sequences) should fix the problem.

**Long Answer:**

Let's look at the error again.

```
 Failure/Error: let(:rubric_in_grenoble){ create(:rubric_in_grenoble) }

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Name has already been taken
```

The exception tells us we are trying to create a record with a name twice also
I can see a `uniqueness` validation in `Province.name`.

```
class Province < ApplicationRecord
  enum terrain: [:sea, :plains, :hills, :mountains]
  validates :terrain, presence: true
  validates :name,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: true,
            format: {
                with: /\A[A-Za-z ]{3,30}\z/,
                message: "province name has to contain letters and spaces only"
  }
  has_many :populations

 ##some methods
end
```

You didn't paste the `Province` factory, but I expect factory is something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :my_factory, class: "Province" do
    name 'blabla'
    # other fields
  end
end
```

So we have to use sequence instead of static value.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :grenoble, class: "Province" do
    sequence(:name) { |i| "BLABLA#{(i+64).chr}" }
    # other fields
  end
end
```

### Assign same Province

```
RSpec.describe Population, type: :model do

  let(:my_province){ create(:my_province) }
  let(:rubric_in_wroclaw){ create(:rubric_in_wroclaw, province: :my_province) }
  let(:javan_in_wroclaw){ create(:javan_in_wroclaw, province: :my_province) }
end
```

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right about my problem. But I need solution, where two Populations will be associated to exactly the same province.  Thanks : ).

Comment: @Milord check the answer again.